# Array of Struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have two structs - property and owner.

```
struct owner {
    string ownerName;
    string ownerID;
}
struct property {
    string location;
    uint sqFeet;        
    owner[] owners;
}
```

I want to keep track of the owners of a property. So the current owner of a property will be the owner who was added last.

```
mapping(uint => property) selectedProperty;
function createProperty(string memory l,uint sf,string memory on,string memory OID,string memory PID) { //PID is calculated based on property information
     selectedProperty[PID].location = l;
     selectedProperty[PID].sqFeet = sf;
     selectedProperty[PID].owners.push(owner(on,OID));
}
function display(uint PID) public view returns(property memory) {
     return selectedProperty[PID]
}
```

When I display the property details in remix, I get the following as output
0: tuple(string,uint,tuple(string,string)[]): London,4000,0,Mike,NTX670

Why 0 is displayed?

Comment: There is no reason to expect exactly that. Suggest you post a small complete contract that compiles including `pragma` for the precise compiler version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's returning the result just fine. If you're just wondering why the 0 is there, that's just the index of the return. If you were to return two objects like the example:

```
function foo() external returns(uint, uint){
    return(7,12)
}
```

Then the output would look like:

```
decoded output: { "0": "uint: 7", "1": "uint: 12" }
```